# Touchscreen with Qt5 embedded not working

Tags: linux, qt5, framebuffer

I have qt5 embedded with Linux. My touchscreen does not work when I run my program with Linux frame buffer, for example:

```
./myprog -plugin tslib:/dev/input/event0
```

More details:

- `ts_calibrate` works fine
- when I run my program with `./myprog -platform eglfs`, touchscreen works fine
- my environment:

  ```
  TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event0
  USER=root
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Qt-5.3.2/lib/
  TSLIB_TSEVENTTYPE=INPUT
  OLDPWD=/usr/local/Qt-5.3.2
  HOME=/root
  QTDIR=/
  TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
  QT_QPA_EVDEV_KEYBOARD_PARAMETERS=/dev/input/event1
  TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/ts
  TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
  LOGNAME=root
  TERM=vt102
  QT_QPA_EVDEV_TOUCHSCREEN_PARAMETERS=rotate=270
  PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
  QT_QPA_GENERIC_PLUGINS=evdevmouse:/dev/input/event0
  TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
  SHELL=/bin/sh
  QWS_DISPLAY=powervr
  QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0:rotation=0
  PWD=/root
  QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib
  TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
  ```
- Qt 5.3.2 `config.status` :

  ```
   configure -verbose -confirm-license -release -no-xcb -no-pch -icu -tslib -qpa eglfs -no-c++11 -no-cups -no-gtkstyle -make libs -opensource -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtenginio -skip qtimageformats -skip qtlocation -skip qtmacextras -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialport -skip qttranslations -skip qttools -skip qtwebkit-examples -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras -xplatform linux-omap3-g++ -qpa eglfs -qpa linuxfb -evdev
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Qt's support of `tslib` is iffy.  I found that part of Qt tries to implement gestures, but part of Qt tries to map touches to mouse clicks.  In my own experience, the result was unfinished/dropped gestures.

Comment: How I can use touchscreen in Qt5 with linuxfb. What technology I can use for it?

Comment: Take a look in `QWSTslibMouseHandlerPrivate::readMouseData()` with your debugger, and you'll see the key part.  And study the call stack.  BTW, you haven't said if you're wanting touches to be mouse clicks or gestures.  Though not as sexy as gestures, clicks are *far* simpler to get working.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find a solution. If not, try this :

1. Specify the TSLIB DEVICE

   export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event0
2. On some device you have to enable the TSLIB support (on my board it's not required)

   export QT_QPA_FB_TSLIB=1
3. Launch your application

   ./myCuteQt5App -platform linuxfb -plugin tslib

Everything should work properly (in my case works like a charm ;) ).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `evdev` available, you might have more success using that for input.  I've used the following with success:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb
export QT_QPA_GENERIC_PLUGINS=evdevtouch,evdevmouse,evdevkeyboard
export QT_QPA_EVDEV_KEYBOARD_PARAMETERS=grab=1
```

Answer (score 0):

as of tslib version 1.3, you could use the included ts_uinput daemon to create an evdev input device. Point your evdev environment to it and you'd have tslib filtered and calibrated touch input without using QT's tslib plugin.